# How to find multiplicative persistence in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I am trying to find the multiplicative persistence of a number in the Scheme language. Persistence is how many times a function can be applied before it continues. For example, 231 become`2*3*1 = 6*1 = 6` and has a persistence of 2. I have tried to get started on this problem, but am unable to continue/ I do not know how to continue.

```
(define (mp a)
  (define (num-digits n)
    (cond (( < n 10) 1)
          (else
           (+ 1 (num-digits (/ n 10))))))
  (cond ((< a 10) 1)
        (else
         (floor (/ a (expt 10 (- (num-digits a) 1)))))))
```

(mp 4098)

;the above code results in the number 4, and I thought about continuously decreasing the number so I could get each digit. However, that would make the code too long and I wasn't sure how I would continue from there. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by dividing it into parts.

Part (A) The first part is to make a simple function that multiplies the digits of a number together. For example:

```
(multiply-digits 231) ;=> 6
```

Part (B) The second part is to make a function which takes a function and an input and keeps applying the function to the input until it doesn't change.

`(functional-persistence fn x)`

Then you can define `multiplicative-persistence` like this:

```
(define (multiplicative-persistence x)
  (functional-persistence multiply-digits x))
```

---

To complete part (A) you can use recursion with the `quotient` and `remainder` functions to divide the number by 10 repeatedly into its digits. Use an accumulator parameter starting with the value 1 to multiply the values together.

To complete part (B) you can again use recursion to loop and compare the new value `(fn x)` against the old value `x`, when they are `EQUAL?` you can return the value.